# Image processing in microcontroller?

Tags: image-processing, embedded, microcontroller

I have a robot project and it needs to process images coming from a camera.  But I am looking for a microcontroller to have image processing on its own, free of any computer or laptop. Does such a microcontroller exist? What is it? And how is it done?

Comment: What image processing do you really want to do?

Comment: Just a sidenote: There are tons of image processing chips, however microcontroller usually refers to general-purpose CPU:s.

Comment: Btw... you already say "ARM" in subject, so you have the answer there already, no?

Comment: Something like a beagleboard is ARM but can run openCV

Comment: BlackFin Bf70x FTW

Comment: Use a Raspberry Pi which is a credit card-sized microcontroller development board for all the types of tasks you are asking for..!!

Answer (score 9):

I think you're taking the wrong approach to your question. At its core, a microcontroller is pretty much just a computation engine with some variety of peripheral modules. The features that vary generally are meant to fulfill an application where a certain performance metric is needed. So in that respect any generic microcontroller will suffice assuming it meets your performance criteria. I think what you should be asking is:

1. **What computations do you want to perform?** All the major controller vendors offer some sort of graphics processing libraries for use on their chips. You can download them and look through their interfaces to see if they offer the operations that you need. If you can't find a library that does everything you need then you might have to roll your own graphics library.
2. **Memory constraints?** How big will the images be? Will you process an image in its entirety or will you process chunks of an image at a time? This will affect how much memory you'll require your controller to have.
3. **Timing constraints?** Are there certain deadlines that need to be met like the robot needing results within a certain period of time after the image is taken? This will affect how fast your processor will need to be or whether a potential controller needs dedicated computation hardware like barrel shifters or multiply-add units to speed the computations along.
4. **What else needs to be controlled?** If the controller also needs to control the robot then you need to address what sort of peripherals the chip will need to interface with the robot. If another chip is controlling the robot then you need to address what sort of communications bus is available to interface with the other chip.

Answer these questions first and then you can go and look at controller vendors and figure out which chip suits your needs best. I work mostly with Microchip PIC's these days so I'd suggest the dsPIC33 line from that family as a starting point. The family is built for DSP applications as it's peripheral library includes some image processing stuff and it has the aforementioned barrel-shifters and multiply-add hardware units intended for applications like filters and the like.

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible to answer your question without knowing what image processing it is you need to do, and how fast.  For a robot I presume this is real-time processing where a result needs to be available perhaps at the frame rate?

Often a more efficient solution for image processing tasks is to use an FPGA rather than a microprocessor since it allows massive parallelisation and pipe-lining, and implements algorithms directly in logic hardware rather than sequential software instructions so that very sophisticated image processing can be achieved at relatively low clock rates, an FPGA running at just 50 MHz can easily outperform a desktop class processor when performing specialised tasks.  Some tasks would be impossible to achieve in any other way.

Also worth consideration is a DSP, this will not have the performance of an FPGA but is easier to use perhaps and more flexible, and is designed to move data rapidly and to execute instructions efficiently, often including a level of instruction level parallelisation.

If you want a conventional microprocessor, then you have to throw clock cycles at the problem (brute force), then an ARM 11, Renesas SH-4, or even an Intel Atom may be suitable.  For lower end tasks an ARM Cortex-M4, which includes a DSP engine and optionally floating point hardware may be suited.

Answer (score 2):

The [CMUcam3](http://www.cmucam.org/) is the combination of a small camera and an ARM-based microcontroller that is freely programmable.  I've programmed image processing code on it before.  One caveat, however, is that it only has 64 KB of RAM, so any processing you want to do must be done scanline-by-scanline.

Answer (score 1):

Color object tracking and similar simple image processing can be done with [AVRcam](http://www.jrobot.net/Projects/AVRcam.html). For more intensive processing I would use [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) on some ARM Linux board.